# How can I add an operation to the node and user lists?

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I am looking for a way to add entries in the "Operations" Column at:

```
/admin/people
```

and or

```
/admin/content
```

I considered [hook_node_operations](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_operations/7) and [hook_user_operations](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_operations/7)

But those are for adding commands to bulk operations.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the User module in `DRUPAL_ROOT/modules/user` you'll see the `user_menu()` function:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_menu/7

You can add your own operation by making your own [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) that mimics what Core does for the "Permissions" Operation. Its also important to note that these tabs or drop down operations (depending on your theme) are essentially defined as `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` items in the drupal menu system. See below:

```
// What Core does in user_menu() ...
 // Permissions and role forms.
  $items['admin/people/permissions'] = array(
    'title' => 'Permissions', 
    'description' => 'Determine access to features by selecting permissions for roles.', 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
    'page arguments' => array('user_admin_permissions'), 
    'access arguments' => array('administer permissions'), 
    'file' => 'user.admin.inc', 
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );



// You do something similar in your own module ...
  function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['admin/people/foobar_operation'] = array(
      'title' => 'Foo Bar Operation', 
      'description' => 'A form with my custom settings', 
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
      'page arguments' => array('yourmodule_foobar_permission'), 
      'access arguments' => array('administer yourmodule permissions'), 
      'file' => 'yourmodule.admin.inc',
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );

    // Do the same for stuff under admin/content.

    return $items;
  }
```

Hopefully this tidbit helps...